# Is it possible to add a pyqtgraph to a PySide app without using a QLayout?

Tags: pyside, pyqtgraph

I want to add a pyqtgraph plot to my existing PySide application. All of the existing examples use a QLayout of some form to achieve this:

```
from PySide import QtGui
import sys
import pyqtgraph
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
my_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
btn = QtGui.QPushButton("my button", my_widget)
plot = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget()
plotLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
plotLayout.addWidget(plot)
my_widget.setLayout(plotLayout)
my_widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Is it possible to add pyqtgraph plots to my widget without adding it to a layout first? I'm guessing I need to do this because I'm trying to add a widget to a widget. Does pyqtgraph provide something more like QPushButton or QLabel, that can be directly added to the widget?

Answer (score 1):

The widget is `pyqtgraph.PlotWidget()` (which is in your above code). You could add this to another parent widget as you do with other widgets with `pyqtgraph.PlotWidget(parent)` (see the [documentation](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/plotwidget.html) for the list of constructor arguments). This will place it at coordinates `(0,0)` inside the parents widget with a default size (I don't know what this size is or how it is determined - It could have dimensions `(0,0)` or something equally small).

However, typically the hierarchy of objects in a Qt interface should follow Widget -> Layout -> Widget -> Layout -> Widget ... (etc). This allows multiple widgets to be placed inside another widget and spaced and sized properly by the layout. Without layouts, you have to try and manually specify the coordinates and dimensions of each widget. This is possible (but cumbersome) as long as you don't mind widgets not resizing properly when the window size changes.

Given the small amount of overhead to ensure widgets are always inside layouts, and layouts are always inside widgets, I would encourage you to follow that pattern unless you have a specific reason not to.